# Can I say "You will start all again"

Tags: pronouns, prepositional-phrases, objects

Is it right to say "You will start all again"?
I know that 'You will start all over again' is right and I think I can also say 'You will start it all again'.
But can I say 'You will start all again'?

Comment: Instead of "You will start all again" I would say "You will start *everything* again".

Answer (score 2):

Not really.

> You will start all over again

sounds the most natural, although I've never heard it said in that way. Normally, one would say:

> You have to start over

without any again. However, the again isn't wrong technically, it just sounds wrong to me.

The third sentence:

> You will start it all again

sounds like you are telling somebody that they have to, that they **will**, without telling them why.

> You will start all again

isn't right, you need to say what they are starting all over again, for example:

> You will start **it** all again

or

> You will start the activity <s>all</s> again

That also sounds like a firm instruction, as if the person has refused before (I'm reading it with emphasis like this: "*You **will** start all again*"), which may be what you want, but normally it would sound more natural to say:

> Start it all again

Do you have any context? If you provide that with an edit to your question it would be easier to say what you need.